# Crashlytics how to upload dsym files from Carthage frameworks

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics, carthage, dsym

Following the instruction from here https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/advanced-setup.html in order to
automatically upload dSYM file to fabric you just have to run `Fabric.framework/run` script on the app target.

My project configuration is as follow:

```
Project F
- product is Dynamic Framework

Project A
- product is .app
- depends_on:
    - Project F
    - X.framework from Carthage
```

On the target of Project A i've added, as build phase, to run the `Fabric.framework/run` script.
Somewhere in Project F I forced a crash and observed the call stack in Crashlytics. The call stack displays Project F but the symbol say `(Missing)` (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggVBA.jpg)

If I make an archive with all the dSYMs and added manually to crashlytics, the symbols from Project F are shown.

**How can I upload the generated dSYMs automatically to Crashlytics? Can I use a restful api?**

note: I assume the same behaviour will happen for dynamic frameworks imported with Carthage as well.

```
ENABLE_BITCODE = NO

Output Product Directory
- Debug-iphoneos
    - App.app
        - Frameworks
            - ProjectF.framework
            - X.framework
    - App.app.dSYM
    - ProjectF.framework.dSYM
    - X.framework.dSYM
```

> If you link in other static or dynamic frameworks, you could see crash reports with missing line numbers or file information. This information comes from your dSYM files, so ensure that your dSYM files for the frameworks are placed in the same directory as the app’s dSYM and that they are built before your .app. - **[Crashlytics Static or Dynamic Frameworks](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/advanced-setup.html#static-or-dynamic-frameworks)**

As you can see in `Output Product Directory` above, the dSYMs are in the same place, and they appear in the folder before `App.app.dSYM`

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Try switching to using the upload-symbols script which will contain much more output about what's succeeding or failing with the upload: /Applications/Fabric.app/Contents/MacOS/upload-symbols -a <api-key> -p ios /Users/YourUserName/PathToDsymLocation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @MikeBonnell

Found the documentation for upload-symbols script https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html

Since I'm using in an iOS app (and using Cocoapods) I updated my build phase as follows

```
find ${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH} -name "*.dSYM" | xargs -I \{\} ${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/upload-symbols -a <api-key> -p ios \{\}
```